# Download source of URL as string

Tags: vb.net

I want my code to download the source/html of a website and be stored as a string.
For example

Dim source as string = html of website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
Dim thesource As String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://the site u wanna look@")
```